# Selenium is not finding the iframe element

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

This is the website I want to scrape https://anime-hayai.com/play/30148/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88-1-hd.html

I want to scrape scr='....' data from video but it's returning empty string.

**What i have tried**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://anime-hayai.com/play/30148/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88-1-hd.html')

video = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='player']/div[2]/div[4]/video").text
print(video)
```

It's returning `''` empty string.

Is I am doing something wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldf98.png)
**Expected result from video scr**

```
'https://stream.anime-hayai.com/videoplayback?id=6o7ov8-mxpu0aKZQYtLDpMuepaDas4tllm2jqqGUcqDE1c-j0pzahY1pxGuiaJhSteDG5NLdkaaVcotklmRye55ecaGWoJqio46hcs2XyKSmaKZQYqCXoovq'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are nested iframe, so first you have to

1. Switch to first iframe
2. Switch to child iframe

Also, you would need to scroll all the way down.

**Code :**

```
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\panabh02\\OneDrive - CSG Systems Inc\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)


driver.get("https://anime-hayai.com/play/30148/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88-1-hd.html")
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name='video_player']")))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[class='embed-responsive-item']")))
video_url = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='jw-media jw-reset']//*"))).get_attribute('src')
print(video_url)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
https://stream.anime-hayai.com/videoplayback?id=6o7ov8-mxpu0aKZQYtLDpMuepaDas4tllm2jqqGUcqDE1c-j0pzahY1pxGuiaJhSteDG5NLdkaaVcotklmRye55ecaGWoJqio46hcs2XyKSmaKZQYqCXoovq
```

Answer (score 0):

`https://anime-hayai.com/player/30148` is not a text attribute value rather than `src` attribute value.
Also your locator is not so good.
So try this

```py
iframe_src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='video_player']").get_attribute("src")
```

You will possibly have to add a delay / wait before that code line to let the page fully loaded before you going to extract this element content.
Also, you will possibly have to switch to this iframe in order to access it. So, if the above solution still not working try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://anime-hayai.com/play/30148/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88-1-hd.html')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='video_player']"))) 

iframe_src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='video_player']").get_attribute("src")
print(iframe_src)
```

Comment: I got the same error like your code is giving `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[@name='video_player']"}`

Comment: have you tried both ways: to access the iframe element directly and to try switch to it first and then to access it?

Comment: updated questions... Also i have tried both... can you please check in your system ?